# How can I get the content of the block to appear in the view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb

I have some code like this:

```
<% cache "footer_links" do %>
  <%= cms_snippet_content('footer_links') %>
<% end %>
```

And I thought of writing a helper method, like this one:

```
def cached_snippet_content(snip_id)
  cache(snip_id) do
    cms_snippet_content(snip_id)
  end
end
```

However, I don't get any output in my view, even though, my erb code looks like this:

```
<%= cached_snippet_content "footer_links" %>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you make sure the `cache` method is returning a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May the source be with you, Luke:

```
# actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_view/helpers/cache_helper.rb
def cache(name = {}, options = nil, &block)
  if controller.perform_caching
    safe_concat(fragment_for(name, options, &block))
  else
    yield
  end

  nil
end
```

This shows that `cache` is implemented to be called from ERB views, not from helpers. An alternative implementation:

```
def cache(name = {}, options = nil, &block)
  if controller.perform_caching
    fragment_for(name, options, &block)
  else
    capture(&block)
  end
end
```

And now use it with the new Rails ERB style (<%= ... > even in blocks if they output something):

```
<%= cache "key" do %>
  <%= content_tag(:p, "hello") %>
<% end %>
```

I'd test this carefully, there may be hidden corners, I guess there'll be a reason why `cache` has not been adapted to the Rails 3 block style.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the `do` block in your helper method isn't returning anything and hence the entire helper method isn't returning anything and henceforth there's nothing for the view to display.

Maybe try this:

```
def cached_snippet_content(snip_id)
  cache(snip_id) do
    result = cms_snippet_content(snip_id)
  end
  result
end
```

Comment: Still no output. If I call the cms_snippet_content method myself, it returns content, so I would guess the problem is with returning the result from cache somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def cached_snippet_content(snip_id)
  a = ""
  cache(snip_id) do
    a += cms_snippet_content(snip_id).to_s
  end
  a
end
```